# What's the best way to create a dictionary from the difference of two other dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, difference

I have two dictionaries of lists:

```
dic1 = {'a' : [3, 4, 5], 'b' : [0, 1, 2]}
dic2 = {'a' : [3, 4, 5], 'b' : [8, 1, 2, 30], 'c' : [9, 8, 2]}
```

and want a third that only has what is in the second dictionary and not in the first:

```
dic3 = {'b' : [8, 30], 'c' : [9, 8, 2]}
```

what is the most pythonic way of doing that in python `2.7` and below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension to iterate through the items of `dic2` to build a new mapping to the difference between lists of `dic2` and `dic1` of the same keys using set difference, while filtering out keys with identical list values in both dicts:

```
{k: list(set(l).difference(dic1.get(k, []))) for k, l in dic2.items() if dic1.get(k) != l}
```

This returns:

```
{'b': [8, 30], 'c': [8, 9, 2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Without dict comprehension)

You could use `difference` available on `set` objects:

```
dic1 = {'a' : [3, 4, 5], 'b' : [0, 1, 2]}
dic2 = {'a' : [3, 4, 5], 'b' : [8, 1, 2, 30], 'c' : [9, 8, 2]}

for k, v in dic2.items():
    if k in dic1.keys():
        new_v = list(set(v).difference(dic1[k]))
        if len(new_v) > 0: dic3[k] = new_v
    else:
        dic3[k] = v
```

This will provide the desired output.

Comment: That's close to what I was typing when I thought to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If any key of `dic2` is not present in `dic1` or value corresponding to any key is different in both dictionary, then add that key, value pair in another dictionary.

```
 for k in dic2.keys():
   if (k not in dic1.keys()) or (dic1[k] != dic2[k]):
     dic3[k] = dic2[k]
```